# I need a query for children that start with my name but doesn't start with any in that set

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have a table with text primary key called "name". Given a name (that may contain any arbitrary characters including %), I need all of the rows from that table that start with that name, are longer than that name, and that don't start with anything else in the table that is longer than the given name.

For example, suppose my table contains names `ad`, `add`, `adder`, and `adage`. If I query for "children of ad", I want to get back `add`, `adage`. (`adder` is a child of `add`). Can this be done efficiently, as I have several million rows? Recursive queries are certainly available.

I have a different approach at present where I maintain a "parent" column. The code to maintain this column is quite painful, and it would be unnecessary if this other approach were reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell about its efficiency but I think it works:

```
with cte as (
  select name 
  from tablename  
  where name like 'ad' || '_%'
)
select c.name
from cte c  
where not exists (
  select 1 from cte
  where c.name like name || '_%'
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cgU1BGvLcpDNz2dTjtSiUE/0).
Equivalent to the above query with a self LEFT JOIN:

```
with cte as (
  select name 
  from tablename  
  where name like 'ad' || '_%'
)
select c.name
from cte c left join cte cc
on c.name like cc.name || '_%'
where cc.name is null
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cgU1BGvLcpDNz2dTjtSiUE/2).
Results:

```
| name  |
| ----- |
| add   |
| adage |
```

Comment: Why should it be recursive? Also what do you mean *for 2 levels*? Can you post sample data for which it does not work?

Comment: yeah I see what you mean -- the % deals with all issues.

Comment: From testing, the upper query is quite a bit faster than the "outer join" query. However, it's still too slow for my present need, taking bout 5 seconds to execute on a table of 81k items.

Comment: Try also without a CTE: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cgU1BGvLcpDNz2dTjtSiUE/3

Comment: Alas it's still too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use left on the column like this:

```
 select *
 from sometable
 where lower(left(name,2)) = 'ad' and length(name) > 2
```

Comment: this query doesn't do the hard part of eliminating children of the children. sorry

Comment: @Brannon ah I did not understand that requirement the first time I read it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be recursive. It's not clear to me whether or not that is the only way.